# How to mention about my university's MOU with the university in which I'm applying for Research Internship?

Tags: research-undergraduate, email, international-students, internship

My university has an MOU (Memorandum of Understanding) with certain universities in which I am interested in applying for the position of research intern.

As I will be mailing professors of my domain of those universities for the internship, how should I mention in the mail that my university has an MOU with their university?

PS: My university's International Programme and Collaborations Department said, while applying to a university, if the student mentions the existence of an MoU, it may increase his/her chances to receive an acceptance from the university.

Comment: An MOU can mean anything.  You need to be more specific as to the content of the MOU.